# Change the width of a svg with an animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have a `svg` image inside this object:

```
<object id="firstrule" type="image/svg+xml" data="/assets/rules/pertinance.svg"></object>
```

I want to make it appear on scroll with an animation. I have coded the good callback for the scroll, and now I'm stuck with how to make the animation.

The animation would be: in the beginning, the svg has 0 width, and when the callback is triggered, the svg now takes its normal size of 100%. The animation should takes 3 second, and during those 3 seconds, we can see the image changing size from 0 to 100%.

To do this, I tried the following thing:
1) Set a width attribute to my object "firstrule" of 0%

```
<object id="firstrule" type="image/svg+xml" data="/assets/rules/pertinance.svg" width="0%"></object>
```

And 2) Triggering an animation with jquery

```
$('#firstrule').animate({'width':'100%'},3000);
```

It doesn't work, and I got this error on my browser's console: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'cur' of undefined`

Do you know another solution (maybe using CSS3?), or how to fix this? I'd like an easy solution, not to bother with a lot of lines, nor any plugin. I'm pretty sure that it is possible to overcome this issue lightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple workaround: Place the `<object>` with your SVG image inside a wrapping `<div>`. Then animate the container and not the object.

```
<style>
    #wrapper { width: 0; }
    #firstrule { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <object id="firstrule" 
        type="image/svg+xml" 
        data="/assets/rules/pertinance.svg">
    </object>
</div>

<script>
    function animate() {
        $("#wrapper").animate({ width: "100%" }, 3000);
    }
</script>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Hxfd/)**

Comment: Exactly what I wanted ! Between, would you mind explaining me why should we set the svg inside a wrapper please?

Comment: The wrapper is necessary because it's obviously not possible to animate `<object>` elements directly with jQuery. However, even though I checked the relevant parts in the jQuery source, I can't explain to you why that is...

Comment: Indeed, it is not possible, but possible by using Hristo Georgiev solution using pure js (setInterval). It's weird

Answer (score 1):

If you want to directly interact with the object, you can always rely on the good ol' javascript:

var i = 0;

var repeat

```
function animate() {


    repeat = setInterval(function () {
        add();
    }, 1);

    function add() {
        document.getElementById("firstrule").style.width = i + '%';
        document.getElementById("firstrule").style.height = i + '%';
        i++;
        if (i >= 100) {
            clearInterval(repeat);
        }
    }


}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3Hxfd/9/)

Comment: This is by far the most ingenious solution, thanks you. But the animatin doesn't stop after three seconds, and I need something simpler, so I chose Aletheios answer ;)